# Magento 1.9 - How to get JSON config by a bundle item id in cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, json, product-edit

When I have a bundle product in the cart, I can edit it by clicking the edit button . At this point, a page with the product to edit will be loaded. Also, a function named "getJSONConfig()" will be called in order to load the product data. I only need this function, how can I call it having the item_id only?